# Calculate the growth rate of a complicated function

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm familiar with calculating and comparing the growth rates of basic functions. For example, I understand that

$ \log_b n\prec n^r\prec a^n \prec n!\prec n^n$ for $a>1$, $b>1$ and $r>0$.

However, I was wondering how we can calculate the growth rate of a more complicated function such as this one?

$f(x)=\frac{-\ln\left(1-\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}\right)}{\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{d-1}{d}}}$ for an interger $d>1$ when $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Any thoughts would be much appreciated!

**Edit:**
My attempt is as follows.

Since $\frac{1}{x}\rightarrow 0$ when $K\rightarrow \infty$, we can write
$\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)^{\frac{1}{d}}\approx 1-\frac{1}{dx}$. Thus, the numerator can be simplified roughly into $\ln\left(dx\right) =\ln c+\ln x$. Would it be valid for us to suggest that $f(x)$ grows approximately as $\ln x$?